# Broadcast over Array Dimension

Tags: julia

Let's say I have a two-dimensional array

```
a = [1 2 3; 1 2 3]

2×3 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2  3
 1  2  3
```

and I would like `sum` along a dimension, e.g. along dimension 1 yielding

```
[2, 4, 6]
```

or along dimension 2 yielding

```
[6, 6]
```

How is  this done properly in `Julia`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
julia> sum(a; dims=1)
1×3 Array{Int64,2}:
 2  4  6

julia> sum(a; dims=2)
2×1 Array{Int64,2}:
 6
 6
```

You can drop the dimension with `vec`.

Answer (score 6):

What Jun Tian suggests is the standard way to do it. However, it is also worth to know a more general pattern:

```
julia> sum.(eachrow(a))
2-element Array{Int64,1}:
 6
 6

julia> sum.(eachcol(a))
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 2
 4
 6
```

In this case `sum` can be replaced by any collection aggregation function.